# Dynamic class declaration options

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to have the option for the user to select variable different classes based on an user input. Unit_Alpha and Unit_Beta are two different classes that the user can choose from for the unit. Both Classes have the run() function that takes the same inputs and return value, but they do different calculations. As a result I don't think they can be the same class. When I dim the unit in the select case, visual basic does not like it. Is there a way to allow this or an alternative method?

Thanks in advance.

```
    Select Case unitsearch.Text
        Case "Alpha"
            Dim unit As New Unit_Alpha
        Case "Beta"
            Dim unit As New Unit_Beta
        Case Else
            MsgBox("no unit properly selected")
            Exit sub
    End Select
    Answer = unit1.run(variables)
```

Comment: What's the signature for the `Run` method, and what is `unit1`?

Comment: @sebslaman, please edit the question title: "decoloration" -> "declaration" ...

Comment: @MathieuGuindon and example of one run function is:

Public Function Run() As Integer
        Return Form1.d6() ' random number between 1 and 6
    End Function

Comment: What I was getting at, is that if the two classes have the same signature for the `Run` method, then you could have a common interface, say `IUnitSearch` with a `Public Function Run(ByVal value As String) As Integer`, and then both `UnitAlpha` and `UnitBeta` (avoid underscores in type names) could implement that interface, and then you would do `Dim search As IUnitSearch` and then do `search = New UnitAlpha` or `search = New UnitBeta`, and get intellisense against `IUnitSearch` when you make member calls on the `search` object. Works in VBA as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

closely sticking to the question I'd propose:

```
Dim unit As Object
Select Case unitsearch.Text
    Case "Alpha"
        Set unit = New Unit_Alpha
  Case "Beta"
        Set unit = New Unit_Beta
  Case Else
      MsgBox ("no unit properly selected")
      Exit Sub
End Select
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work for me, however visual studio warns me that when i use MsgBox(unit.run()) that "variable 'unit' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime." However, it still runs.

Comment: Note: "Set" may not be supported, and "unit = New Unit_Alpha" has worked without the "Set".

Comment: You are welcome. And you are in VB.NET, aslo.... Please edit question tags!

Comment: @sebslaman, resorting to late-binding as this answer demonstrates should be your last resort and is not advisable when more definitive coding methodologies such as using an interface are available.  I realize DisplayName posted this in good faith and assumed a VBA environment, but VBA also supports declaring and using interfaces.

Comment: @TnTinMn I'm not exactly sure as to what you mean. I'll give interfaces a look and see how/if I could be able to use them to do what I want.

Comment: I second TnTinMn's comment.  I would strongly recommend to follow Joel Coehoorn's advice below and use an interface.  Interfaces are designed for exactly this use case.

Comment: @Craig, is it you downvoting?

Comment: Yes, because the answer is (in my opinion) a last resort and Joel's answer is much better practice.  As I said, interfaces are designed for exactly this use case.  The questioner will be a better .NET developer (or, for that matter, VBA/COM developer) if he understands how to use interfaces and apply them to problems that they are well-suited to solving.

Comment: @Craig, this answer came from VBA tag only, where people, with very few exceptions (some two or three of them) don’t know what interfaces are. TnTinMn got that, maybe you wil, too

Comment: I was comfortable using interfaces in classic VB (and thus VBA) long before I was using them in .NET.  I think the advice holds equally there; interfaces are fundamental to the design of COM, which was built hand-in-hand with the object model of VB/VBA.  If anything, it's *more* important to understand and be comfortable with interfaces in VBA if you are already working with classes, given the lack of inheritance.

Comment: I've coded in classic VB, VBA (which is the same language engine, just lacking the forms library and native code compiler), and .NET VB.  I've written some fairly complex code (which included classes) in Excel before.  I had worked fairly extensively with VB classic before I did any significant work in Excel VBA, though, so I've always been comfortable using all of the language features when I work in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

You want both `Unit_Alpha` and `Unit_Beta` to implement the same interface. Let's call it `IUnit`:

```
Interface IUnit
    Sub Run(variables As String) 'guessing at arguments here
End Interface

Public Class Unit_Alpha Implements IUnit
   '...
End Class

Public Class Unit_Beta Implements IUnit
    '...
End Class
```

Then your existing code will look like this:

```
Dim unit As IUnit
Select Case unitsearch.Text
    Case "Alpha"
        unit = New Unit_Alpha
    Case "Beta"
        unit = New Unit_Beta
    Case Else
        MsgBox("no unit properly selected")
        Exit sub
End Select
Answer = unit.Run(variables)
```

Alternatively, it **is possible** to have this all in one class, if you replace the `Run()` member method with a `Func` delegate. Then the `Select` block can change the delegate based on the user's choice. But that may be a bit beyond where you're at.

Comment: was that you downvoting my answer?

Comment: Unit_Alpha and Unit_Beta both have different versions of the Run() function, where as in here the function looks like it would be the exact same. How would I be able to have them different?

Comment: No, this would not be the same. `unit` is an `IUnit` variable. Both `Unit_Alpha` and `Unit_Beta` implement the `Run` method for the `IUnit` interface. When you call `unit.Run()`, you will use the implementation from either `Unit_Alpha` or `Unit_Beta`, depending on what was assigned to the variable.

Comment: It was my downvote. I checked the question right before leaving town for the day. Looking again with more time, I see the tag was changed after you answered. I stand by a downvote suggesting to use `Object` and `Set` here for a VB.Net question, but for VBA, as it showed when you answered, it makes more sense.

Comment: That’s what actually happened. And I regret both having answered and suggested to change tag. Since this got me in touch with NET people

Comment: @DisplayName Don't be discouraged by criticism of your answer; I think I learn the most when I make a suggestion and have people tell me that it's wrong (and why/how to improve).